# first and last order SAS

Tags: sas

I have two lines of data,

Order
17/01/2016
01/02/2014

Basically I want to run a logic like so;

```
data A.test_active;
set A.Weekly_Email_files_cleaned4;

length active :8.;
length inactive :8.;
if first.Order between '01Jan2014'd and '31Dec2015'd then active= 1;
if last.order between '01Jan2014'd and '31Dec2015'd then inactive= 1;

run;
```

the field "Order" is formatted by DDMMYY10 when I checked the file properties, but I keep getting this error
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

Can anyone help or suggest something different in the same vain?

Answer (score 2):

In SAS, `between` is only valid in `SQL` contexts: either actual `PROC SQL`, or `WHERE` statements, generally.  It is not otherwise valid in SAS.  You would use `in (firstval:lastval)` instead, *if* those values are integers (dates are).  If they're not integers, you need to use `if firstval le val le lastval` or similar (can also use `ge/lt/gt/>/<` or whatever you like, depending on the ordering of things).

Second, `first.order` and `last.order` are boolean values - 1 or 0, nothing else, that indicate that you are on a row that is the first row for a new value when sorted by that variable, or the last row similarly.  You also must have a `by` statement by that variable if you're going to use them.

Third, your length statements are wrong; you're confusing some three different things here, I think.  Length statements for numerics aren't needed if you're using default length 8, and if you do like having them anyway, you need:

```
length active 8;
```

No `:` or `.`, both are used for different purposes.

Comment: thanks Joe, I think there might be another way to get to what I am trying to do, whilst I corrected the above code, not sure its achieving what I need. , I reposted my query below, can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ID     first_order      Order
 alex      01/01/2013     23/01/2015
 alex      01/01/2013     23/01/2015 
 alex      01/01/2013      03/04/2013
```

basically if an order exists after the first order that is within a certain timeframe (within a year of the date of the first order) then the user is "active"

any ideas much appreciated
thanks